# Remembering Custom and Third Party Cookies Post Django Login

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-authentication

I've noticed that logging in a user using django.contrib.auth.login deletes *all* custom and third party cookies previously set. This is breaking lots of things, such as my Google Web Optimizer tests, which can no longer track the user. What's the best way to prevent this when logging in a user?

Looking at the code for login() in `django/contrib/auth/__init__.py` doesn't show a lot of customizability, and the culprit seems to be line `request.session.flush()`. My first thought was to simply copy the request.COOKIES dictionary before the call to login(), and then copy it back to the request post-login, but I'm not sure what Django cookies to exclude.

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the session code that would dink with your cookies.  `flush()` and the three methods it calls doesn't do much of anything with the cookies, and the middleware just calls `response.set_cookie()`.  Are you certain it isn't somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Are your sure flush is always called? i remember flush is only called when _auth_id exists in the session? logout does flush the session always for security reasons (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6941)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure your cookies are really on the same domain?

```
Two different domains
www.mysite.com
mysite.com
```

I've never had django screw with cookies, but I have had www vs non-www cookie issues.